# Visual Studio and console window to see Echo from batch file

Tags: visual-studio

I'm getting familiar with VS2008. I made a batch file, with some Echo statements.
I have the batch file running after a successful build.
Is there a console window that I may see the echo outputs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, look at the `Output` window.

To get the output window, Go to `View -> Output` or `Ctrl+W, O`

Comment: yes, it sounds like that's what i want, how/where do i find it?

Answer (score 0):

To display the Output window, select Output from the View menu.